# Just as I did / just as I found

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense

Are

> I found this, just as I found that.

and

> I found this, just as I did that. [omitted "find"]

equal? Additionally I would like to replace "just as" with "like", but I'm not sure if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are semantically equivalent, and the second sentence works because *do* acts as a pro-verb (note: *not a proverb*) and equates to another verb in the agnate construction, namely *found*.

You may be able to insert *like* into that sentences, but only if you would be substituting it for *as*. That is:

> I found this, like I did that.

Note that this might be considered informal, and you can leave the *just* in:

> I found this, just like I did that.

The difference in meaning is that there is a particular emphasis on the second clause where *just is used*, though the comparison remains in either case.